# Does Spring Data Elasticsearch support Amazon Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

From the research I have done it seems that the two do not work together because of HTTP only support for Amazon Elasticsearch.

Hoping someone can clarify if in fact it is not something that is possible with Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From different discussions:
 - [Spring data ES and searchly](http://support.searchly.com/customer/portal/questions/9746977-spring-data-elasticsearch-and-searchly)
 - [port for the transport protocol](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=683536)

and the [AWS documentation on ES service limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html); go to the bottom, the last line says:

> > The service supports HTTP on port 80, but does not support TCP transport.

It's not yet possible to use Spring Data ES which uses the Java APIs, with Amazon service which only available through REST.

Comment: It is possible, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009873/does-spring-data-elasticsearch-support-amazon-elasticsearch/61193214#61193214

Answer (score 7):

Looks like Spring data elastic search from version 3.2.0 works with http rest client, so it is possible to connect to aws elastic instance through Rest API and port 443. Somehow they integrated spring-data-jest approach into spring data.
I use RestHighLevelClient:

```
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(awsUrl)));
    }
```

awsUrl format is: *https://some_aws_generated_address.us-east-n.es.amazonaws.com:443*

NOTE: If you are using spring boot with default bom.xml, you need to upgrade spring boot to 2.2.1.RELEASE or newer

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice project providing Jest implementation of Spring Data ES that works with AWS managed ES service.

Checkout
https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest

Answer (score 1):

> **It is possible to use Spring Data Elasticsearch with Amazon Elasticsearch**

As Excerpt from Spring-data elastic search [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.transport)

> TransportClient is deprecated as of Elasticsearch 7 and will be
> removed in Elasticsearch 8. This is in favor of Java High Level REST
> Client. Spring Data Elasticsearch will support the TransportClient as
> long as it is available in the Elasticsearch.
>
> The Java High Level REST Client now is the default client of
> Elasticsearch, it provides a straight forward replacement for the
> TransportClient as it accepts and returns the very same
> request/response objects and therefore depends on the Elasticsearch
> core project

**Spring Data ElasticSearch** has streamlined with the latest standards of **ElasticSearch**, hence from `spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.X` it provides a flexible way to achieve a custom `RestHighLevelClient`.([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/config/AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration.html#elasticsearchClient))
Even though it is possible to use HTTP based elastic search API calls with or without authentication, it will not solve the problem associated with the AWS elastic-search API calls.

Because any **HTTP requests** to **AWS services or APIGW backed services** have to follow **`"Signature Version 4 Signing Process(SigV4)"`** which eventually adds authentication information to AWS requests sent by HTTP. For security, most requests to AWS must be signed with an access key, which consists of an **`accesskey ID`** and **`secret access key`**. Hence, we have to follow the standards when calling the AWS ElasticSearch service.

**Let's get our hands dirty with code and delve deep into the implementation**

Please follow the steps:

**Step 1: Adding required dependencies**

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.346</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Step 2: Adding AWS CredentialsProvider**

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AWSCredentialsConfiguration {

    @Value("${aws.es.accessKey}")
    private String esAccessKey = null;

    @Value("${aws.es.secretKey}")
    private String esSecretKey = null;

    @Bean
    public AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsDynamoCredentialsProviderDevelopment() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                esAccessKey, esSecretKey));
    }
}
```

Or if your Application running on AWS instance and you don't want to use the property-driven/hardcoded AccessKey and SecretKey then you have to assign the **IAM role** to your **Amazon ECS task** [for more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-iam-roles.html).

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AWSCredentialsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProvider() {
        return new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper();
    }

}
```

**Step 3: Adding ElasticSearchRestClientConfiguration**

- If you observe the below code we are providing a custom implementation of `**RestHighLevelClient**` to abstract method `**AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration#elasticsearchClient()**`. In this way, we are injecting the incorporated customRestHighLevelClient of **`"elasticsearchOperations"`**, **`"elasticsearchTemplate"`** beans into the spring container.
- **`HttpRequestInterceptor`** is another important thing to notice. A Special thanks to [AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor.java](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor.java), a sample implementation provided by **`AWSLabs`** helps us to add the interceptor to the RestClient with the **`AWS4Signer`** mechanism.
- **`@EnableElasticsearchRepositories`** annotation help to enable the elasticsearch data repositories.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.config.AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;


@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.demo.aws.elasticsearch.data.repository")
public class ElasticSearchRestClientConfiguration extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${aws.es.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint = null;

    @Value("${aws.es.region}")
    private String region = null;

    @Autowired
    private AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        String serviceName = "es";
        signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
        signer.setRegionName(region);
        HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(serviceName, signer, credentialsProvider);
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(endpoint)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(e -> e.addInterceptorLast(interceptor)));
    }
}
```

Bravo Zulu! that's it. We have completed the configuration part. Now with this solution, you can leverage the spring-data elastic benefits along with Amazon elastic search service. The complete solution has been documented in [Medium Post](https://medium.com/@prasanth_rajendran/how-to-integrate-spring-boot-elasticsearch-data-with-aws-445e6fc72998)

If there are any issues related to permission regarding accessing indices (ex: refresh), you can add the permission using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943777/3303074)

Comment: Does not work. I'm getting  [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden] {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}]. While connecting directly via RestHighLevelClient works

Comment: @shark, for the corresponding error, you have to check with your `AWSCredentialsProvider`. Please validate your credentials `accessKey` and `secretId`. I have been using this snippet for more than 2 microservices. I have not seen such 403 issue

Comment: I have DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain and I also checked if it takes valid key and it does. What is curious This code creates indexes correctly but has problem with storing entity

Comment: Should I do anything specific with permissions, roles etc ? My instance is public

Comment: DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain  takes credentials in the following order.
`
Environment Variables or Java System Properties or Web Identity Token credentials from the environment or container or Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
`. Index creation works fine means your API calls authentication works correctly, you have to check the role for your AWS service, whether you have access to perform write operation for the index.

Comment: I have restricted access using the index pattern similar to `dev-*`, `nonprod-*` and have assigned role to the ECS instance which using ES. Similarly, you have to check the same with your credentials, Check using Kibana devtools with your credentials, if you are able to do write operations to index then you are on track or else you have to adjust your role permission

Comment: @Vinod, it should work with spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.2.2.RELEASE   aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:1.11.346, I have production running applications with the above versions

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran I had a similar issue now this can occur due to multiple reasons: To validate this please insert any records from Spring boot endpoint to AWS Elasticsearch do check are you able to see the record in the Kibana view or not and if you see the record being inserted and still getting the error 403 that is because of AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor.java file issue; please do get the file from Github (awslabs). Ideally in this case search by id and find all should work. The second case can be a version issue check Elasticsearch version and spring boot parent version.