# JHipster Elasticsearch with Amazon Elasticsearch Service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

My question is simple, can I use JHipster Elasticsearch with Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no,
The ticket for this feature request is here:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2794
This functionality does not work as AWS Elasticsearch Service does not expose the transport protocol port (9300) needed by Spring Data.

More info here:
[Does Spring Data Elasticsearch support Amazon Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009873/does-spring-data-elasticsearch-support-amazon-elasticsearch)