# How to setup Elasticsearch cluster nodes to use DNS rather ip address

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have installed Elasticsearch v2.3.5 on an EC2 instance in AWS and there are multiple applications accessing it. We'd like to control the cluster nodes via a route53 entry rather than hard coding the IP addresses which are not stable in AWS, particularly if the cluster needs to grow. The DNS name would reference 1 or more A records which comprise the nodes in the ES cluster.

All applications are created with spring-boot 1.4.0 which is configured with

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes={ip-address}:9300
```

Can it be changed to a domain name? say

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=elastic.example.com:9300
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Create a internal load balancer add the nodes to that internal LB and then point your domain to that load balancer.

Comment: Have you considered using the Amazon Elasticsearch Service instead of hosting your own cluster in EC2? You wouldn't have to worry about the IP changing and it might make some other things easier.

Comment: Thanks jbird but its not an option we have.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009873/does-spring-data-elasticsearch-support-amazon-elasticsearch