# ElasticSearch no permissions for [indices:data/read/msearch] despite having the permission

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm running into the weirdest permission issue for `_msearch`.

When running simple _search with the same query, everything runs perfectly.

`POST /job/_search`

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"s","fields":["title"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"or","fuzziness":2}},{"multi_match":{"query":"s","fields":["title"],"type":"phrase","operator":"or"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"s","fields":["title"],"type":"phrase_prefix","operator":"or"}}],"minimum_should_match":"1"}}}}]}},"size":10,"_source":{"includes":["*"],"excludes":[]}}
```

When running it with `_msearch` I get the permission error

`POST /job/_msearch`

```
{}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"s","fields":["title"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"or","fuzziness":2}},{"multi_match":{"query":"s","fields":["title"],"type":"phrase","operator":"or"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"s","fields":["title"],"type":"phrase_prefix","operator":"or"}}],"minimum_should_match":"1"}}}}]}},"size":10,"_source":{"includes":["*"],"excludes":[]}}
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "no permissions for [indices:data/read/msearch] and User [name=public_api, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "no permissions for [indices:data/read/msearch] and User [name=public_api, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"
    },
    "status": 403
}
```

Here are my permissions in Kibana:

[image]

I am running an OpenDistro in AWS ElasticSearch Service.

Comment: please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943777/3303074)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by setting the following cluster permissions:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I have solved the above permission problem using the following steps

- Login to `Kibana` using `admin` or user with `higher previledges`

1. Click `security` option

   [image: Step]
2. Click `roles` option and then select the desired role for your user based on your requirement. In my case, the user requires all access so selected `all_access` role
3. Click `Mapped users` then click `Manage mapping` option.
4. In the `Users` section type/paste the `IAM-arn/internal-user` and then press enter
5. Finally, click the map

That's all, the user will be mapped to the role and corresponding permissions, thereafter you will not face the permission issue mentioned in the question

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by not using fine-grained access control.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Bolein95, which works perfectly, If anyone looking for Terraform Permissions, you could add the following Cluster Permissions:

```
cluster_permissions = ["indices:data/read*", "indices:admin/mappings/fields/get*"]
```